# NSURLConnection in initWithNibName?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, viewdidload

I dont know but since using iOS5 (now 5.1) and Xcode 4 (now 4.3) , ViewDidLoad gets called everytime no matter what. I have to retrieve a JSON output from an API, but if I put the fetching code in ViewDidLoad, it gets called everytime. So my question is, is it OK/Legal(from Appstore perspective) to use the NSURLConnection code in `initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` ?

Heres the code

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        jsonContent=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        stateConnection= [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY API"]] delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Edit: its not working. the NSURLConnection code doesnt work in this method. so what should i do so that it gets called only once?

Comment: When "viewDidLoad" is getting called, why don't "initWithNibName" get called? If you call "initWithNibName", then only "viewDidLoad" will also gets called. Isn't it?

Comment: yea thats true, but breakpoints dont seem to work on that method. Anyways how do i ensure that the connection is made only the 1st time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly "legal" to put code in the init method as you describe. Indeed, as you note, it's possible for `viewDidLoad` to be called multiple times (for example after a low memory warning).

As for why your code isn't working, I don't think there's enough context to be sure. Is the code in the `if` block actually being executed? My guess is no. If you're using iOS5 and Storyboards, the `initWithNibName` method isn't used. If you put the same code in an `initWithCoding:` method you might have more success.

Comment: Yes i am using storyboards. Thanks for the advice. Well I stored the JSON output in an array in NSUserDefaults and now I check if that array exists in defaults then the connection is not called. Hows this method?

Comment: @AkashMalhotra Sounds okay as long as there are not huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

Its perfectly fine to put that code into `viewDidLoad`. Just check, if you already initialised it.

```
if(jsonContent == nil) {
    jsonContent=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    stateConnection= [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY API"]] delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    }
}
```

With that check you could even start it later (if it fits your needs better, like in `viewWillAppear' or`viewDidAppear', or even after pressing a button or anything else.